# cowboy_websocket:websocket_send argument problem

Tags: erlang, cowboy

I am trying to use cowboy to send a notification to multiple clients using the socket connected to them. The problem is that I cannot find anything in the documentation about the argument to be passed to the function, the one I used in the code seems to be incorrect.

The socket is saved in a variable called Req that is given when a new client connects in the init function:

```
% Called to know how to dispatch a new connection.
init(Req, _Opts) ->
  ?LOG_INFO("New client"),
  ?LOG_DEBUG("Request: ~p", [Req]),
% "upgrade" every request to websocket,
% we're not interested in serving any other content.
  Req2=Req,
  {cowboy_websocket, Req, #state{socket = Req2}}.
```

The sockets are used in this way

```
send_message_to_sockets([Socket | Sockets], Msg) ->
  cowboy_websocket:websocket_send(Socket, {text, Msg}),
  send_message_to_sockets(Sockets, Msg).
```

This is the error:
Error in process <0.202.0> with exit value:
{undef,[{cowboy_websocket,websocket_send, [#{bindings => #{},...}

I have tried different argument to be passed to the function websocket_send but nothing worked.

Here is the code of the websocket_send:

```
transport_send(#state{socket=Stream={Pid, _}, transport=undefined}, IsFin, Data) ->
 Pid ! {Stream, {data, IsFin, Data}},
 ok;
transport_send(#state{socket=Socket, transport=Transport}, _, Data) ->
 Transport:send(Socket, Data).
-spec websocket_send(cow_ws:frame(), #state{}) -> ok | stop | {error, atom()}.
websocket_send(Frames, State) when is_list(Frames) ->
 websocket_send_many(Frames, State, []);
websocket_send(Frame, State) ->
 Data = frame(Frame, State),
 case is_close_frame(Frame) of
  true ->
   _ = transport_send(State, fin, Data),
   stop;
  false ->
   transport_send(State, nofin, Data)
 end.
websocket_send_many([], State, Acc) ->
 transport_send(State, nofin, lists:reverse(Acc));
websocket_send_many([Frame|Tail], State, Acc0) ->
 Acc = [frame(Frame, State)|Acc0],
 case is_close_frame(Frame) of
  true ->
   _ = transport_send(State, fin, lists:reverse(Acc)),
   stop;
  false ->
   websocket_send_many(Tail, State, Acc)
 end.
```

Comment: I don't see any `websocket_send` in https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.9/manual/cowboy_websocket.

Comment: There is no trace of that function in the documentation but it exists, infact my IDE does not complain. I don't know if I am doing the right thing, maybe there are other ways to handle websocket communication in erlang. If you have an idea it could be useful.

Comment: Ah, it seems that function exists but is private: https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/blob/master/src/cowboy_websocket.erl. I'm not too familiar with ranch/cowboy, but it seems you'll have to send a message to the socket, and add a `websocket_info` clause which creates the reply, similar to `handle_info` with plain `gen_server`s.

Answer (score 0):

> The socket is saved in a variable called Req that is given when a new
> client connects in the init function:
>
> ```
> init(Req, _Opts) ->
>   ?LOG_INFO("New client"),
>   ?LOG_DEBUG("Request: ~p", [Req]),
> % "upgrade" every request to websocket,
> % we're not interested in serving any other content.
>   Req2=Req,
>   {cowboy_websocket, Req, #state{socket = Req2}}.
> ```

I don't think that is true.  In Nine Nine's Cowboy User Guide, there is a section titled [Getting Started](https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.6/guide/getting_started/), which shows this code:

```
Handling requests
...
...

    init(Req0, State) ->
        Req = cowboy_req:reply(200,
            #{<<"content-type">> => <<"text/plain">>},
            <<"Hello Erlang!">>,
            Req0),
    {ok, Req, State}.
```

In that code, `init()` is passed a map that is assigned/bound to the Req0 variable.  You can read about the Request map here:

https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.9/guide/req/

The map contains the usual HTTP Request information, e.g. the HTTP Request method, the HTTP version number, scheme, host, port, path, etc.  Then the docs say:

> Any other field is internal and should not be accessed.

Generally, a socket is defined like this:

> A socket is one endpoint of a two-way communication link between two
> programs running on the network.

And:

> An endpoint is a combination of an IP address and a port number.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/definition.html

In this line:

```
cowboy_websocket:websocket_send(Socket, {text, Msg}),
```

[websocket_send()](https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/blob/master/src/cowboy_websocket.erl#L622) is defined to take a `cow_ws:frame()` type as the first argument:

```
-spec websocket_send(cow_ws:frame(), #state{}) -> ok | stop | {error, atom()}.
websocket_send(Frames, State) when is_list(Frames) ->
```

In the [cow_ws module](https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.9/manual/cowboy_websocket/), the `frame()` type is defined like this:

```
frame() :: {text, iodata()}
           | {binary, iodata()}
           | ping | {ping, iodata()}
           | pong | {pong, iodata()}
           | close | {close, iodata()} | {close, close_code(), iodata()}
```

...which is a tuple with the first element being an atom and possibly a second element being an `iodata()` type, which is a built in erlang type that is a binary or a list (containing integers, binaries and other lists), and it is defined here:

[image]

I'm not sure how you go from a Request map to a two-tuple.